# Dev Container Not Starting

Tags: vscode-remote

I am trying to open my project using a dev container via VS Code.

I clicked on "Reopen in Container," the Dev Container terminal opened, and it prompted me to open docuemantion about [tips and tricks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_container-tips).

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here is the devcontainer.json

```json
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/alpine
{
    "name": "Alpine",
    // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:alpine-3.17"

    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    // "features": {},

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "uname -a",

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    // "customizations": {},

    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "root"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Docker Desktop, you must check the `WSL integration` settings to ensure your default WSL distro and any other distros are enabled.

[image]